# BarChart bar value labels are hidden by the margin

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

I am using Jaspersoft Studio to create the report file with charts.

When I use the bar chart and try to display the bar values labels these are covered by the margins. In my opinion this looks like a bug, is there any way to show the labels properly?

To better illustrate the problem you can see the issue on the picture and also find in red the expected values.

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is my progress customizing the bar chat. So far I could make several changes but I am stuck with the most important one.

[image]

I tried using huge values for the margins without any visual effect.

```
    rangeAxis.setUpperMargin(200);
    rangeAxis.setLowerMargin(200);
```

I also played with the bounds. In that case I can see the entire labels but the problem is that the values won't stop at 100 (so that is not a valid solution).

I discovered the reason why the margins are completely ignored:

> public void setUpperMargin(double margin)
>   Sets the upper margin for the axis (as a percentage of the axis range) and sends an AxisChangeEvent to all registered listeners. **This margin is added only when the axis range is auto-calculated - if you set the axis range manually, the margin is ignored.**

But if I remove the margins then the bounds are autocalculated from 0-125 what is not the scope.

As usual, any suggestion will be welcome.

For a better understanding you can download the sample code from my GitHub repository.

GitHub: https://github.com/MichaelKnight/jaspertest.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart in jasper report is generated by the [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) library. In your case you can:

1) Set the range axis upper margin to give more space to value label (see jfreechart BarChartDemo5).

2) Draw the label inside the bar (see jfreechart BarChartDemo7) *After edit if you need fixed upper value of axis you need to use this, hence the label has no space left if upper limit equals max bar value*

To customize your bar chart in jasper report create a customizer class (MyChartCustomizer) extending the [JRChartCustomizer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRAbstractChartCustomizer.html). This will expose:

```
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, ChartComponent chartComponent)
{
  //Simple example of increasing upper margin on range axis, to print label
  //inside of bar see jfreechart BarChartDemo7
  CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
  NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
  rangeAxis.setUpperMargin(0.20); //Increase or decrease to change upper margin in percentages (0 --> 1.0)
  rangeAxis.setAutoRange(true); //make sure that fixed range is not set
}
```

add the class to classpath and in jrxml set the `customizerClass` attribute

```xml
<barChart>
    <chart customizerClass="my.package.MyChartCustomizer">
   ....
    </chart>
   ...
</barChart>
```

Comment: I tested your code. There is one little change: I need to use `JRAbstractChartCustomizer` otherwise I get ClassCastException. Once I made that change I could run your code but I didn't get any result. I will play a bit more.

Comment: You are right sorry, that or just implement the JRChartCustomizer, check out the JFreeChart examples, you can do a lot of stuff with the chart.

Comment: I already tested your proposal and so far is not a valid solution. I explored other ways to do it without much success. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @MichaelKnight, did you see any difference?, is your chart customizer called?. I tested in jfreechart and increasing the upper margin works, if you do not have fixed range... I edit the answer to ensure autorange..