# BarChart set values axis increment

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am using JasperReports to generate a report with charts. One of them is a bar chart and I'd like to set the increment of the axis values in 20 units.

You can see my previous approach at this link: [BarChart bar value labels are hidden by the margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428223/barchart-bar-value-labels-are-hidden-by-the-margin)

This is my customizer class:

```
    public class BarChartCustomizer extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart jFreeChart, JRChart jrChart) {

        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) jFreeChart.getPlot();
        plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(numberFormat);
        BarRenderer barRenderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        barRenderer.setItemMargin(0.0);
        rangeAxis.setUpperMargin(0.20);
        rangeAxis.setAutoRange(true);
        CategoryAxis categoryAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
        categoryAxis.setAxisLineStroke(new BasicStroke(2f)); 
        rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setAxisLineStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
    }
}
```

I tried with `rangeAxis.setMinorTickCount(20);` with no success.

As usual, the final solution will be included in the sample code located in my GitHub repository: https://github.com/MichaelKnight/jaspertest.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(20));
```

Also see the net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.tick.interval property (documented at http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.tick.interval), which does exactly that.

Comment: That's perfect!  It was exactly as you said.